# Blender hangs at command window

Tags: command-line

I cant start Blender right now. I used --debug to get some info about that. Unfortunately I only can see this:

```
Switching to fully guarded memory allocator.
Blender 2.79 (sub 0)
Build: Thu 03/22/2018 09:59 AM Windows
argv[0] = blender
argv[1] = --debug
```

My OS is Windows 10 and I have a Nvidia 780. Blender is at the most recent version. I tried also reinstalling and deleting the user preferences in Roaming. Right now I can't think about anything else to provide further information. Does anyone have a hint what I could do?

Comment: You could download the stand alone/.ZIP version and then run it from separate location.

Answer (score 1):

After starting up Linux I wanted there to mount the windows partitions. NTFS filesystem couldnt be mounted though since Windows was not shut down properly (which is not true). I cleaned the state and mounted them, worked with blender, then restated into windows. Blender then worked again. Not sure now if that was coincidence or if this was the result of sth else I did... but perhaps it's worth a try if someone runs into this problem.